# Is it possible selecting only edges with edge selection mode in the UV editor like in edit mode?

Tags: uv, edges, uv-image-editor

Using edge selection in edit mode you can select adjacent edge loops and use individual origins as pivot point to edit them separately, for example.

[image: Adjacent loops selected independently]

Meanwhile, edge selection mode in the UV editor behaves like vertex selection mode, so you can't select adjacent loops independently.

[image: Selecting adjacent loops in the UV editor will select all interconecting edges and faces even in edge select mode]

Is there a way to work with edges like in edit mode?

Thanks in advance.

Version is 2.93.5

Comment: Over the UV EDITOR on the left of the "vertex selection " icon, there is an icon with two arrows turn it on and everything that you select on the 3d viewport will be selected on the UV editor too

Comment: The result is the same, I'm aware of that feature, in the UV editor it will look just like on the second image of my post.

Comment: Not sure how you got into that state.  I just checked on 2.93.5 and if I have the object in edit mode with all vertices selected (so that the entire UV maps shows up in the UV editor) I can select individual edges in the UV editor. can you share a blend file that shows the problem? ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))

Comment: I could send a blend file, but I just checked with a freshly open default scene and it has the same problem. I even checked loading factory preferences.